# Length l1 +1 => what is one for?

Tags: haskell

```
agrupa :: String -> [(Char,Int)]

agrupa [ ] = [ ] 

agrupa (x:xs) = let (l1, l2) = span' (==x) xs  

                in (x, (length l1) + 1) : agrupa l2 

span' :: (a->Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])

span' p l = (takeWhile p l, dropWhile p l)
```

this function gets a string and gives us how many of each character are there?

my question is related to the `1` in `(length l1) + 1` why do we need it?
I'd really appreciate if you explain it with different example because such cases (like+1) I've seen lots of times also in scan( or debug only the agrope part please) the function to see how it works exactly?

thanks for your time

Comment: Why do you define `span'` rather than using [`Data.List.span`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:span)?

Answer (score 6):

The `+ 1` is there because you've previously matched one of the `== x` elements away, namely `x` itself, in the pattern `(x:xs)`. If you didn't consider that, a list with no duplicates would give all `0`s in the `snd` of each tuple in the result; as you have it the `snd` always gives the actual number of consecutive elements.

Comment: then when we are using let's say if x == maximum (x:xs) then

Comment: Usually, there is no good reason to _put in_ `x:xs` as an argument to a function. You'll either be deconstructing a list (in your case, with `agrupa (x:xs) = ...`, or cons-ing up another one, in which case you first need to calculate the new head and tail. Of course, you could also write `agrupa (x:xs) = y:ys` `where {y = (x, length l1 + 1); ys = agrupa ls; ...}`. That's just trivial restructuring of your implementation.